# Is this identity true for operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

We have the classical identiy:
$$ \boldsymbol{L}\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{p}\times\boldsymbol{L}\right)  = 0$$

But I was wondering if that is also right in QM, considering $L$ and $P$ do not generally commute. I tried to check it:

$$\boldsymbol{L}\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{p}\times\boldsymbol{L}\right)=L_{i}\left(\boldsymbol{p}\times\boldsymbol{L}\right)_{i}=\epsilon_{ijk}L_{i}p_{j}L_{k}=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{imn}r_{m}p_{n}p_{j}\epsilon_{kou}r_{o}p_{u}$$

$$=\epsilon_{kij}\epsilon_{kou}\epsilon_{imn}r_{m}p_{n}p_{j}r_{o}p_{u}=\left(\delta_{io}\delta_{ju}-\delta_{iu}\delta_{jo}\right)\epsilon_{imn}r_{m}p_{n}p_{j}r_{o}p_{u}$$

$$=\epsilon_{imn}r_{m}p_{n}p_{j}r_{i}p_{j}-\epsilon_{imn}r_{m}p_{n}p_{j}r_{j}p_{i}=\epsilon_{imn}r_{m}p_{n}p_{j}\left(r_{i}p_{j}-r_{j}p_{i}\right)$$

It does seem like it isn't going to be zero, but I have a deep feeling I'm missing something. Will be glad for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to finish your calculation:

$$
\begin{align}
\epsilon_{imn}r_{m}p_{n}p_{j}\underbrace{\left(r_{i}p_{j}-r_{j}p_{i}\right)}_{\delta_{ij} i\hbar} &= \epsilon_{jmn} r_m p_n p_j \\
&= 1/2 \left(\epsilon_{jmn} r_m p_n p_j + \epsilon_{jmn} r_m p_n p_j\right) \\
&= 1/2 \left(\epsilon_{jmn} r_m p_n p_j + \epsilon_{nmj} r_m p_j p_n\right)\\
&= 1/2 \left(\epsilon_{jmn} r_m p_n p_j - \epsilon_{jmn} r_m p_j p_n\right)\\
&= 1/2 \left(\epsilon_{jmn} r_m p_n p_j - \epsilon_{jmn} r_m p_n p_j\right)\\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$